# Implicit Java to Scala collection conversion does not work

Tags: scala

I often occur the problem that although I imported the `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` converters into my scala file, the implicit conversion does not happen.

Assume the following code (where `submissionStorage.get` is some Java function returning a Java Map)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable

...

val submissions: java.util.Map[String, String] = submissionStorage.get(formname)
val submissionJavaKeys: java.util.Set[String] = submissions.keySet()
val submissionScalaKeys: mutable.Set[String] = submissionJavaKeys
```

Leds into the following compile error:

> type mismatch;  found   : java.util.Set[String]  required:
>   scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]

Now the [documentation of the JavaConverters](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$) states that there is a conversion "scala.collection.mutable.Set <=> java.util.Set", so exactlly what I need here.

What am I doing wrong, so under which conditions do the JavaConverters work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaConverters` adds `asJava` and `asScala` methods. You want `JavaConversions` instead.